# What is the difference between accounts and users tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

With 26 questions tagged [accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts), 19 questions tagged [users](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) and 4 questions tagged [users+accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users%2baccounts) it is unclear to me when to use which.

Should these two tags be merged? Or, if not, how should their tag-wikis be updated, so their use cases would be distinct and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts) should be for questions involving services that offer accounts, such as iTunes.
[users](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) should be for questions involving user accounts, such as those on OS X.

As neither has a wiki, it's unsurprising that people have gotten confused. It's cleanup time!